# Is $f(x)=|x|$ a convex function?

Tags: functions

While reading an article on Convex functions, I came across the following [statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function):

> The absolute value function $f(x)=|x|$ is convex (as reflected in the triangle inequality), even though it does not have a derivative at the point $x = 0$.

Now we know that $f^{'}(x)=1,\text{ for }x>0$ and $f^{'}(x)=-1,\text{ for }x<0$. Considering all values of $x\neq0$, we can still conclude that $f^{''}(x)=0$ for all $x\neq0$. But a function is said to be convex iff $f^{''}(x)>0$. Where ami I going wrong? Is there another definition for convex functions?

Comment: Lot's of definitions:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function  but what you describe with f''(x) > 0 is **strictly** convex.  Regular convex would be f''(x) \ge 0.  The geometric definition is that the points in a line segment between to points lie above *or on* the graph. If we require above and never on then we are talking *strictly* convex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) a convex function is "... if the line segment between any two points on the graph of the function lies above or on the graph"

Also (again Wikipedia), "If f is twice continuously differentiable and the domain is the real line, then we can characterize it as follows - $f$ convex if and only if $f''(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$".

But your function is not twice continuously differentiable.

Answer (score 22):

Here is an another proof which I find easier to understand as it involves an alternative definition of convexity (which is more intuitive I find...)

#### Definition of convexity

Let $f$ be a real function defined on a real interval $I$, $f$ is *convex on* $I$ if and only if:

$$ f(\alpha x + \beta y) \leq \alpha f(x) + \beta f(y)$$

$$ \forall x,y \in I \ : \forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}, \ \alpha + \beta = 1 \ $$

#### Proof that $f(x) = |x|$ is convex:

Let $x,y \in R$ and $\alpha, \beta \in R_{\geq0}$ subject to $\alpha + \beta = 1$

\begin{aligned}
 f(\alpha x + \beta y ) & = |\alpha x + \beta y| &\text{Definition of $f$}
 \\
 & \leq | \alpha x | + | \beta y|  &\text{Triangle inequality}
 \\
 & = | \alpha | |x| + |\beta|  |y| &\text{Absolute value is multiplicative}
 \\
 & = \alpha f(x) + \beta f(y) &\text{By definition}
\end{aligned}

[source 1](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Convex_Real_Function)

[source 2](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Absolute_Value_Function_is_Convex)

Comment: Does triangle inequality require positivity of numbers?

Answer (score 3):

What is incorrect is your definition of convex functions.

According to the wikipedia page you linked, a function is called convex if 
$\forall x_1, x_2 \in X, \forall t \in [0, 1]: f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)\leq t f(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2).$

This is not equivalent to $f''(x)>0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall x_1, x_2 \in X, \forall t \in [0,1],  f(tx_1+(1-t)x)2) \leq tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2)$$

Can you check that $|x|$ is indeed convex using this definition? Hint: Triangle inequality.

The corresponding case when second derivative exists is $f^{"}(x) \geq 0$

Answer (score 0):

Lots of definitions: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function but what you describe with $f''(x) > 0$ is *strictly* convex. Regular convex would be $f''(x) \ge 0$. The geometric definition is that the points in a line segment between two points lie above *or on* the graph. If we remove the "or on" options and  require above and *never* on then we are talking *strictly* convex.

postscript:  well $f''(x) > 0$ is not a definition of strictly convex either.  ... *sigh*....

if $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x$ but then $f$ is strictly convex but the converse needn't be true. But I think if $f$ is strictly convex and $f$ *is* doubly differentiable then $f''(x) = 0$ can only occur for at most one $x$.  I *think*.  And, of course, $f$ need not be doubly differentiable everywhere.

Anywhoo....  a linear function $f(x) = mx + b$ is technically convex.  And that is doubly differentiable everywhere $f''(x) = 0$.

Comment: I meant to say about the same thing, one might want to add a caveat though in that I'd find it odd for say $x^{4}$ not being strictly convex even though $f''(0)=0$. Thus the characterization via the deriviative is not really one. There is also a notion of *strongly* convex, which amounts to $f''$ being bounded away from $0$.

Comment: (x^4)'' = (4x^3)'=12x^2 \ne 0 and ... oh you meant not...  I see.  Hmm.  I guess when someone says with such earnesty that f'' > 0 is definition...