Concavity where second derivative is undefined at a point but negative everywhere else
I want to say that $y=-|x|^{1.5}$ must be strictly concave since $y'$ is continuous and $y''=-.75/\sqrt{|x|}<0$ everywhere except at $x=0$ where it's undefined. (I'm working in real numbers only.)
Is this a fair claim or does it need further supporting arguments?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937476/is-fx-x-a-convex-function and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function might help.

It's strictly concave on all $\mathbb{R}$ regardless of where the derivative is defined.

You just need $y'$ to be non increasing, which is easily verfied.
